# Importing data from csv to mariaDB missing first column

Tags: mysql, bash, csv

I have a .csv file with 4 columns. I'm having trouble inputting the first column into the table. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

_csvfile="/logstash/Mysql-Data.csv"

#Create the tables if they dont exists


mysql -u user -ppassword logstash << eof
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`elkDevIndexAssoc\` (
    cenDevSID varchar(255),
    cenDevFQDN varchar(255),
    cenDevIP varchar(255),
    cenDevServiceName varchar(255)
  )
eof


#Format the csv, replace ";" with ","
sed -i -e 's/;/,/g' $_csvfile
#sed -i -e 's/^/,/g' $_csvfile
IFS=, 
while read column1 column2 column3 column4 
  do 
    echo "INSERT INTO elkDevIndexAssoc (cenDevSID,cenDevFQDN,cenDevIP,cenDevServiceName) VALUES ('$column1', '$column2', '$column3', '$column4');" 

done < Mysql-Data.csv | mysql --user='user' --password='password' -D logstash;
```

The output looks fine if i echo each column variable, e.g $column1 - 4. Like this:

```
123213 serverfqdn 127.0.0.1 mysql
```

But when i then try to import it to mysql, the first column is missing, like this:

```
mysql> select * from elkDevIndexAssoc;
+-----------+------------------------------------------------+----------------    -+--------------------+
| column1 | column2                                     | column3            | column4  |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------+----------------  -+--------------------+
 |column1 | column2                                     | column3         | column4
         |  | serverfqdn            | 127.0.0.1  | mysql
```

I dont understand how the first column is missing when i import it to mysql but not when i echo each variable individually?

EDIT: My .csv file is formatted like this:

```
S123123,serverfqdn,127.0.0.1,service
S123123,serverfqdn,127.0.0.1,service
S123123,serverfqdn,127.0.0.1,service
S123123,serverfqdn,127.0.0.1,service
```

Comment: As far as I can see you should place your mysql command behind your echo command inside the loop.

Comment: could you add some lines of your csv please? (head -n5 Mysql-Data.csv), and truncate your table to not have any relicts (truncate logstash)

Comment: Sure, i've added it to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql-command should be inside your loop:

```
while read column1 column2 column3 column4; do 
  echo "INSERT INTO ..." | mysql --user='user' --password='password' -D logstash;
done < Mysql-Data.csv
```

OT: you don't need a semicolon to terminate mysql command inside echo string.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. Result is still the same only with more output on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this way it shoud work (tested locally):

```
IFS=,
while read column1 column2 column3 column4; do
  echo "INSERT INTO elkDevIndexAssoc (cenDevSID,cenDevFQDN,cenDevIP,cenDevServiceName) VALUES ('$column1', '$column2', '$column3', '$column4')"
done < <(sed 's/;/,/g' < Mysql-Data.csv)
```

`sed` does not modify your csv file, but your loop reads from. In my example the loops input is coming from behind `done`. Take care for the `IFS=,` it will have influence to all the rest of your script, so it would be better to limit it to the `sed` command (somehow).

The script above expands your data to this:

```
INSERT INTO elkDevIndexAssoc (cenDevSID,cenDevFQDN,cenDevIP,cenDevServiceName) VALUES ('S123123', 'serverfqdn', '127.0.0.1', 'service')
INSERT INTO elkDevIndexAssoc (cenDevSID,cenDevFQDN,cenDevIP,cenDevServiceName) VALUES ('S123123', 'serverfqdn', '127.0.0.1', 'service')
INSERT INTO elkDevIndexAssoc (cenDevSID,cenDevFQDN,cenDevIP,cenDevServiceName) VALUES ('S123123', 'serverfqdn', '127.0.0.1', 'service')
INSERT INTO elkDevIndexAssoc (cenDevSID,cenDevFQDN,cenDevIP,cenDevServiceName) VALUES ('S123123', 'serverfqdn', '127.0.0.1', 'service')
```

Pipe this output of the echo command inside the loop to your mysql:

```
while ...
  echo "..." | mysql -u... -p...
done ...
```

And don't forget to truncate your table before validation, so you don't evaluate old (wrong) data. ;)